# Generate list of tags from search results

Tags: search, tags, terms

On my search results pages I have my tags list too. But I only want to show tags that will filter the results further. So clicking on a tag will filter the result with the search term AND the selected tag.

I'm currently using `get_terms()` & I've tried `'hide_empty'=> true` but that only hides tags that have not been assigned to anything in the site.